# Keep primary monitor in fullscreen while working on the other one

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, fullscreen, multiple-monitors

Sometimes I use 1 screen for games or movies while I can watch some working-progress or just my internet browser on the other one.

So if I want to use the other screen, I always have to minimize the window in fullscreen and this is pretty annoying from time to time.

Is there a way to set the focus to the other monitor and keep the fullscreenmode?

I tried some things with the WinAPI and PInvoke without success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "I tried some things..." - What things, specifically? What effects did you believe they would have, and in what way did they not match your expectations? (I'm not saying that there necessarily is an answer, but it helps to know the false trails someone has already gone down, or that they've found the *right* method but somehow failed to make it work)

Comment: I don't know if you'll consider a tool for fullscreen window switching, but if you do try Desktops.exe of SysInternals I think it's capable of doing this (actually it keeps virtual desktops to switch between so it's not actually window switching but desktop switching)

Comment: My only solution yet, is to run it in Window-Mode and use Clipping but this doesnt work on every program.
I tried to find a normal window via handle (like notepad) but I wasn't even able to set the focus on it, or read in the WndProc-Messages (i'm pretty new to this).
Also I'm afraid that the Fullscreen will minimize automatically as soon as i click somewhere else, so i rather ask here for some helpful tips, than working hours and hours on a solution with a dead-end ;)

Answer (score 1):

the "Win+P" key combination in Windows 7 should allow you to switch between monitors, but I heard it requires both monitors to be at the same resolution to attain fullscreen mode. I'm not at a Windows 7 machine right now so unfortunately I cannot verify it presently.

EDIT: on the other hand, I just found [this](http://www.osnews.com/story/23202/The_win_p_Mess_Will_Microsoft_Ever_Learn_)

Comment: I believe the OP just wants applications running at fullscreen not to minimize upon losing mouse focus, not change the screen arrangement.

Comment: even if it would loose focus how i want it, there is still the problem that the combination doesn't work with the applications i tried..